# Sails size recognition

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition, object-recognition

Is it possible to recognize the height and width of the sails of different kitesurfers and windsurfers taken from public webcams? And show these information on video in real time? Or on screenshots?

Comment: It is likely possible, at least within some level of accuracy (computer vision systems can be applied to all sorts of measurement problems, but are not perfect). Is that really your question, or are you looking for something more specific and technical about the subject? In general the site doesn't like to just say "yes, here's a link" to this sort of question, but to have some useful detail on the topic of AI to add. Is there any part of such a project where you are stuck or want to know in more detail before you attempt the work?

Comment: @NeilSlater thank for your reply. Yes, I'm going to scope and make a feasibility study for an App development project. We want to create an App that improve the Kitesurfers, Surfers and Windsurfers travel experience. We can access several Webcams and we would like to apply some sort of Machine Learning to send notification to Surfers setting different triggers: 1) detect surfers movement, 2) detect and determine kitesurfers sails sizes,3) detect and determine kitesurfers/surfers/wind surfers velocity.
I would need techinal specifications to complete a draft App product requirements document.